# Como gerar um CSS com regra hierárquica usando gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Tenho um arquivo pai chamado: `/assets/hierarchy-file.scss`, dentro dele eu importo os arquivos filhos:

```
@import "./style_guide";
@import './default_styles';

@import './header';

// :::::::::: OS ARQUIVOS DAS PÁGINAS DEVEM COMEÇAR AQUI :::::::::: 

@import './home';

// ::::::::::::::::::::::::: TERMINA AQUI ::::::::::::::::::::::::: 

@import './footer';
```

Usando gulp somente quando eu edito o arquivo pai `hierarchy-file.scss`, o watch escuta ele e pega as alterações dos arquivos filhos. Eu gostaria de quando eu alterar qualquer um destes arquivos filhos, o watch reconhecesse que o arquivo arquivo pai foi alterado: `hierarchy-file.scss`, o que preciso fazer?

```
var paths = {
css:[
    //assets_path+'./assets/css/*.scss',   
    //assets_path+'./assets/css/**/*.scss',   
    assets_path+'./assets/css/hierarchy-files.scss',  
  ]
}

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.css)
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat('css.styles.css'))
    .pipe(gulpif(activeMinify, sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(public_path+'/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
  //  .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.css, ['css']);
});
```

Comment: Basta colocá-los na lista de globs que você passa para o segundo argumento de `gulp.watch`, não?

Comment: A ideia é que o hierarchy-files seja a saída compilada eu não quero gerar os arquivos filhos na pasta pública. Os filhos nada mais são do que conteúdo partials do arquivo pai... como eu faço isso?

Comment: Sim, mas se você colocar mais arquivos na lista de globs não fará diferença alguma na saída, apenas quando o Gulp vai rodar o processo `css`...

Comment: Mas o watch está usando `browserSync`, ou seja, ele está compilando no watch, Digamos, que eu coloque `./assets/css/*.scss`, [...]

Comment: [...] ou seja que quando eu editar qualquer arquivo dentro desta pasta ele passa pelo watch, o problema é que ele não compila o arquivo pai, ele só compila o arquivo filho que estou mexendo...

Comment: Eu queria que toda vez que eu mexer num dos filhos, o pai fosse reescrito.

Comment: Talvez algo como isso: [gulp-css-globbing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-globbing)